# FreeBSD 9.2 (x64) libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: mysql, client, freebsd, ldd

I'm using FreeBSD 9.2 64bit on my dedicated server, and i have library which was compiled on FreeBSD 32bit system. This library using libmysqlclient.so.18 and i have problem becouse i dont know how to install  32 bit version on my 64 bit os without deleting existing 64 bit libmysqlclient.so.18 on my server.

LDD output:

```
ldd ./libgame.so
./libgame.so:
    libthr.so.3 => /usr/lib32/libthr.so.3 (0x28240000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found (0)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0x28260000)
    libm.so.5 => /usr/lib32/libm.so.5 (0x2834d000)
    libc.so.7 => /usr/lib32/libc.so.7 (0x2806c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x28367000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install 32-bit package.

It should be sufficient to provide the missing shared library. Just take libmysqlclient.so.18 from i386 version of mysql55-client package (for instance -- from [portsmon Page](http://portsmon.freebsd.org/portoverview.py?category=databases&portname=mysql55-client)) and place it in /usr/lib32

If libmysql-client depends on some other shared library that's not there, you'll need to repeat the process.